# backbone.js router not responding to url fragments

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a simple router defined and instantiated.

**Problem:** When I go to the url `http://localhost/backbone1/#photos/5`, I expect to see an output from `console.log()` in the javascript console, but nothing shows up. Did i miss out on something?

**JS Code**

```
var GalleryRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "about": "showAbout",
        "photos/:id": "getPhoto",
        "search/:query": "searchPhotos",
        "search/:query/p:page": "searchPhotos",
        "photos/:id/download/*imagePath": "downloadPhoto",
        "*other": "defaultRoute"
    },

    showAbout: function() {

    },

    getPhoto: function(id) {
        console.log('You are trying to reach photo ' + id);
    },

    searchPhotos: function(query, page) {
        console.log('Page number: ' + page + ' of the results for ' + query);
    },

    downloadPhoto: function(id, imagePath) {

    },

    defaultRoute: function(other) {
        console.log("Invalid. You attempted to reach: " + other);
    }



});

var myGalleryRouter = new GalleryRouter();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Router starts listening to url hash changes after you call `Backbone.history.start()`.   Usually, you'd want to load essential data and initialize global views first, then start router.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a initialize method

```
    var initialize = function () {
            var myGalleryRouter = new GalleryRouter();
            Backbone.history.start();
        };
return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
```